# Best way to narrow down a list and rank based on attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ranking

I have a mortgage/credit data set that contains a list of customers (600k rows) and has a 100 columns inclusive of the customer's general info (address, city, zipcode, etc), income, fico scores, number of current mortgages, mortgages in the past, aggregate mortgage amounts, number of bank card trades, etc. The data pertains to customers that are already good candidates to contact for issuing a credit product, however if one is to narrow down the list to 350K:

What would be the best method to rank the list to cut it down?

PS Your insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it a little hard to know how to answer the question. Why do you need to cut the number of records down? If you want to rank them, rank them to what purpose? Ranking implies there are positives and negatives, or at least less positives.

One way you could approach this is to perform PCA. That said, I think you should consider disqualifying some fields, like the address fields.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your guidance, the list of consumers in the data contains the consumers potentially prone to getting a financial product upon being contacted; however the list is too long (600k rows) and my given task is to take the best of these consumers so that I end up with a 300k long list of consumers... So for instance, the consumers with the best credit scores, loan to val ratios etc should be ranked high.... With PCA, the eigenvalues can be used as weights to help me arrive at some sort of score per consumer (linear combination of weights and each attribute value), am I correct?

Comment: hope that's clear?

Comment: You got it. The first principal component is the component that has the most variance. Of course, it may also be inconsequential, so you’re going to have to make a judgement call. But at least it’s not random.